# Problem with pdfcomment and pdfsync

Tags: line-breaking, forward-inverse-search, pdfcomment

I have a problem with using both `pdfsync` and `pdfcomment` together: once I use `pdfsync`, the comment causes a line break, which it shouldn't do. As an example, compile with and without `\usepackage{pdfsync}`:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{pdfcomment}
\usepackage{pdfsync}

\begin{document}
Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text
Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text
\pdfcomment[icon=Note,hspace=0cm,voffset=0cm,hoffset=0cm,width=0cm]{text}
Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text
Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text
\end{document}
```

Comment: The `pdfsync` package should only ever be used for drafts: changes in output are a 'known issue'. Moreover, it is obsolete as SyncTeX is available in both TeX Live and MiKTeX to achieve the same aim at an engine level.

Comment: Ok - thanks, this fixed my problem! I thought I need pdfsync to do the syncing.

Comment: @JosephWright looks like your comment fixed this